# "bachelor's" vs "bachelor's degree"

Tags: idioms, synonyms, sentence

Please consider the following sentence:

> 1. The institution awards degrees including **bachelor's degrees, master's degrees, and doctoral degrees**.

I know that the sentence above is grammatically correct, but I don't like the repetition of the word "degree(s)".

So I'm looking for an alternative with the **exact same meaning**. Here's what I was thinking of using instead:

> 2. The institution awards degrees including **bachelor's, master's, and doctorate**.

Is this second version grammatically correct? Does it "sound" right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects I can see here:

1. Abbreviating "*bachelor's degree*" to "*bachelor's*"
2. Creating a list while omitting repeated words

**Abbreviation**

It is very common to abbreviate both "*bachelor's degree*" to "*bachelor's*" and "*master's degree*" to "*master's*", but it is informal. I don't know whether you're looking for formal or informal phrasing.

The phrase "*doctoral degree*" is new to me. The word "doctorate" I recognise but I don't think of it as as a sort of degree; therefore including it in a list of degrees seems strange. A quick google shows that this is a lack of knowledge on my part, or possibly it's just not phrasing used at universities myself and my friends have attended.

**Omission**

It is common when listing different adjectives with a repeated noun to just put the noun at the end. For example: "*I bought red, green and yellow peppers for my salad*".

In your example this would be "*bachelor's, master's, and doctoral degrees.*" However, this doesn't remove the awkwardness in your situation, because you still have the word "degrees" twice in your full sentence: "*The institution awards degrees including bachelor's, master's, and doctoral degrees.*"

**How I'd word it**

I'd either put it all into one clause rather than two separate clauses:

> "The institution awards bachelor's, master's, and doctoral degrees."

or I'd use a synonym for the first instance of "degrees":

> "The institution awards **qualifications** including bachelor's, master's, and doctoral degrees."

Answer (score -1):

A university gives bachelor degrees, i.e. Bachelor of Arts, Bachelor of Sciences, Bachelor of Engineering.  Note that it's 'bachelor' -- no s and certainly never apostrophe s ('s). It also gives PhD (doctor of philosophy) degrees and master degrees.  So your sentence should be "The institution awards bachelor, master and doctorate degrees. They're awarding degrees -- not bachelors etc. You could also write "... awards bachelors, masters and doctorates." Leave out "degrees".  Definitely no apostrophe, because it's plural, not possessive.

Comment: Thanks, but it actually is a possessive: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/bachelor-s-degree-or-bachelors-degree

My question isn't about the apostrophe, but about whether or not "bachelor's degree" can be shortened to just "bachelor's" in this context.

Comment: It's not a possessive.  The bachelor degree, like the master degree,  isn't a  possessive.  It's the kind of degree, not who owns it. So also a nursing degree, not a nurse's degree, a doctorate degree not a doctor's degree, and so on.  A university awards degrees at the bachelor, master and doctor levels.  Yeah, I know.  This is picayune, but correct.

Comment: Every source I can find online says it's a possessive and that just writing "bachelor" is always incorrect:
https://wmich.edu/writing/rules/degrees
https://www.bachelorsdegreecenter.org/bachelors-vs-bachelors/
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/masters-degree/
https://www.jhsph.edu/news/style_manual/d.html

Comment: @SeymourHamilton Can you provide a source of it being called a bachelor degree when not qualified with something like "of Art"?

Comment: The style guides ([1](http://colby-sawyer.edu/assets/pdf/cs-styleguide.pdf), [2](https://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-academic-degrees)) I've checked have all said it is "bachelor's degree" and "Bachelor of Arts". Maybe you're getting confused with "associate degree" (which isn't possessive).